# No me reconoce atributos booleanos de una clase en otra y los inicializa en false

Tags: java, booleano, paso-por-referencia

Tengo una clase que extiende de JFrame para crear un panel en el que utilizo checkbox entre otros.
Tiene un Button que al pulsar recoge los datos, se asignan a variables, y finalmente todo se imprime en un archivo de txt.

```
JButton botonGenerar = new JButton("Generar");
    botonGenerar.addActionListener(e -> {
        VentanaInformes obj = new VentanaInformes();
        IAccesoInformes informe = new AccesoInformesImp();
        Paciente paciente;
        obj.setFlujoint(flujotxt);
        obj.setPaint(patxt);
        obj.setPvint(pvtext);
        String nombre = nombretxt.getText();
        int paint = obj.getPaint();
        int pvint = obj.getPvint();
        int flujoint = obj.getFlujoint();
        this.pacienteEstable=estabilidad();
        this.hipoGlucemia=glucemia();
        this.hemostasiaACV=hemostasia();
        this.peso=controlPeso(gidok,gidko);
```

La cuestión es que hay parámetros boleanos que utilizaré para mandar escribir un String basandome en los checkbox marcados. Por ello he creado los métodos dentro de la clase que me retornan true o false en función de los criterios.

```
 public boolean controlPeso(JCheckBox gidok,JCheckBox gidko ) {
    boolean peso=false;
    if (gidok.isSelected() && gidko.isSelected()) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Solo 
    una opcion de control de peso");}
    else if(gidok.isSelected()) {peso=true;}
    else if (gidko.isSelected()) {peso=false;}
    return peso;

}

 public boolean estabilidad() {
    boolean estable = false;
    if (establecheck.isSelected() && hipoTAcheck.isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Estable, no es compatible con HipoTA ");
    } else if (establecheck.isSelected()) {
        estable=true;
    } else if (hipoTAcheck.isSelected()){
        estable=false;
    }
    return estable;
}

public boolean glucemia() {
    return hipoGlucemiacheck.isSelected();
}
public boolean hemostasia() {
    return hemostasiacheck.isSelected();
}
```

Estos valores true o false se asignan correctamente a mis variables dentro de la clase

```
        this.pacienteEstable=estabilidad(); //true
        this.hipoGlucemia=glucemia(); //false
        this.hemostasiaACV=hemostasia(); //true
        this.peso=controlPeso(gidok,gidko); //false
```

El problema viene cuando quiero llevarme estas variables a la clase donde implemento el método para agregar datos al archivo txt. En esta clase los atributos siempre están en false aunque en la clase de origen están correctos.

```
public void escribirPaciente(String nombreFichero, Paciente paciente, boolean anexar) throws 
EscrituraDatosEx {
    File fichero = new File(nombreFichero);

    try {
        PrintWriter salida = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fichero, anexar));
        salida.append("\n");
        salida.println(paciente.toString());
        salida.println(mensajeNormofuncion(paciente));

        /*
         Aquí siempre dan false. obj es un objeto de la clase que extiende de JFrame para 
         acceder a esos atributos boleanos
        */
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        salida.println(mensajePeso(obj.peso));
        salida.println(mensajeEstabilidad(obj.pacienteEstable));
        salida.println(mensajeGlucemia(obj.hipoGlucemia));
        salida.println(mensajeCoagulacion(obj.hemostasiaACV));

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        salida.close();
        System.out.println("Se ha escrito informacion al archivo");
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new EscrituraDatosEx("Excepcion al escribir:" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Para intentar que sea lo mas comprensible muestro los métodos que retornan los Strings en función del boleano pasado como argumento

```
public String mensajeGlucemia(boolean hipoglucemia) {
    String mensaje;
    if (hipoglucemia) {
         mensaje = "Bajadas en la cifra de glucemia por debajo del rango o muy ajustadas, "
                + "\nteniendo que administrar glucosa en ocasiones para evitar 
                   sintomatología";
    }else{
        mensaje = "No hay incidencias respecto cifras de glucemia";
    }
    return mensaje;

}

@Override
public String mensajePeso(boolean peso) {
    String mensaje;
    if (peso==false) {
        mensaje = "Paciente con mal control de peso, con ganancias interdialisis elevadas. "
                + "\nse va por encima de peso seco pautado frecuentemente ";
    } else {
        mensaje = "Paciente con buen control de peso, con ganancias interdialisis moderadas. "
                + "\nse va en peso seco pautado frecuentemente ";
    }
    return mensaje;
}

@Override
public String mensajeEstabilidad(boolean estable) {
    String mensaje;
    if(estable==true){
        mensaje="Paciente generalmente estable durante los tratamientos \ncon " +
                "buena tolerancia a las sesiones y sin incidencias a reportar";
    }else {
        mensaje="Paciente inestable, con incidencias reportadas en cuanto a tolerancia \nde " 
                +
                "las sesiones. Manifestado con sintomatología asociada a la hipotensión";
    }
    return mensaje;
}

@Override
public String mensajeCoagulacion(boolean coagulacion) {
    String mensaje;
    if (coagulacion) {
        mensaje = "Presenta dificultades a la hora de cuagular FAV. \nprecisando mas de 20 
                   min" +
                  "y en ocasiones aplicar medidas locales para favorecer la hemostasia";
    }else {
        mensaje = "No presenta dificultades para la hemostasia";
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```

}

He cambiado modificadores de acceso, los he declarado en ambas clases, no se que está mal para que en esa clase se establezcan en false si en la de origen adquieren los valores correctamente.

Comment: por lo que he leído, obj es **otro objeto**, y entiendo que lo que tu necesitas está en el objeto `persona`. cómo inicializas Obj? le pasas los parámetros de `persona` a `obj`?

Comment: el objeto **paciente** es un objeto creado a partir de la **clase Persona** con sus atributos. Aquí no he tenido problema. El problema viene de la clase **VentanaInformes** que es la que tengo extendida de JFrame, y donde están todos los checkbox, el button, etc. En esta clase inicializo las variables 
        this.pacienteEstable=estabilidad(); //true
        this.hipoGlucemia=glucemia(); //false
        this.hemostasiaACV=hemostasia(); //true
        this.peso=controlPeso(gidok,gidko); //false  Por tanto, obj es un objeto de esta clase con el cual pretendo acceder a esas variables

Comment: La cuestión es que en la clase **VentanaInformes** si se ejecutan los metodos correctamente al pulsar el boton, y me retornan los boleanos que corresponda asignandoselo a esas variaibles. Sin embargo, al acceder a ellas desde el objeto **obj** en la otra clase, todas están en false y por tanto **los métodos que retornan Strings** trabajan con una variable false solamente

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente, estableciendo **static** las variables booleanas que me interesaba usar en la otra clase he podido acceder a ellas sin la necesidad de crear un objeto que al parecer daba problemas.
Mi interfaz grafica tiene el constructor **VentanaInformes()**, mismo nombre que su clase. AL crear un objeto de esta clase en otra para acceder a los atributos

```
VentanaInformes obj =new VentanaInformes();
```

ese objeto (obj) me daba problemas ya que creo,por el constructor, vuelve a inicializar todo el formulario y al acceder a las variables obtiene el false por defecto ya que en esta "construccion" que se realiza de nuevo, ya no se pulsa el boton.